# Extract Xunit test class name from ITestOutputHelper object (C# )

Tags: c#, .net, xunit

Can I use the ITestoutputHelper injected object to get the calling class name?

Comment: See xunit github [#416](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/416)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek This is a good solution for test name but i dont see there any test class..

Comment: ITest has TestCase which has TestMethod which has TestClass which has Class which has Name.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek It worked, that's great. You should post it as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

After a great comment by @ZdeněkJelínek, I end up implementing this static extension function to `ITestOutputHelper`.

```html
        public static string GetTestClassName(this ITestOutputHelper helper)
    {
            var type = helper.GetType();
            var testMember = type.GetField(FieldName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            return((ITest) testMember.GetValue(helper)).TestCase.TestMethod.TestClass.Class.Name;
    }
```

Comment: Most Excellent!